Is there a keyboard shortcut to toggle the size of tabs in Visual Studio Code's split view?
When working with split views in Visual Studio Code, I often find myself in situations where I'm working on a file with limited tab space due to multiple open tabs. I've noticed that double-clicking on the file name in the tab expands its size, and double-clicking again resets it to the original size. Is there a way to replicate this behavior using a keyboard shortcut? I'm looking for a quick way to toggle the size of tabs without relying on mouse interaction.
Maybe you know a solution that could be very handy to me!

You can set a keyboard shortcut by using the View: Toggle Editor Group Sizes (workbench.action.toggleEditorWidths)command. You can set a keyboard shortcut combination for this command in two ways:
First way: Set it from the Keyboard Shortcuts panel:

Open the Keyboard Shorcuts panel from File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts or the Manage icon at the left bottom or just use Ctrl + K + S keyboard combination
Search the View: Toggle Editor Group Sizes or workbench.action.toggleEditorWidths command in the search bar, and you will see this window, it has no keybinding yet since it hasn't a default keyboard shortcut. Click on this line and set a keyboard shortcut. Then, you can change the tab size by using this keyboard shortcut

Second way: Set it from the keybindings.json file:

Open the Keyboard Shorcuts panel from File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts or the Manage icon at left bottom or just use Ctrl + K + S keyboard combination
Open the keybindings.json file from the right top corner file icon
(Displays this overlay on hover: Open Keyboard Shortcuts) in the Keyboard Shortcuts panel.
Then, you can add this command there by using these configurations:

{
   "key": "Write your shortcut combination here",
   "command": "workbench.action.toggleEditorWidths"
}

Hope, it's clear and helpful

I couldn't help but thank you even though Stack Overflow says to avoid it. Crystal clear and very helpful.

@n8te.98 Perfect to hear that. You're welcome!
